# Show checkboxes within diagram legend does not work well if scrollablePlotArea is configured

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, legend-properties

**Highcharts Version v6.1.0**

If you want to have swipable diagrams on mobile or a specific viewport you can activate `chart.scrollablePlotArea` https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea

And if you want to use the checkbox feature `plotOptions.series.showCheckbox` within the same diagram, it will happen that your checkboxes are not visible or they'll scroll with the diagram on swiping the chart. This happens because they're placed in the `highcharts-scrolling` div. From my opinion, the checkboxes should be placed within the `highcharts-fixed` div.

Seems like an Issue in the highcharts lib, but I'm not sure.

**In the following, we found another problem:**
If you want to use HTML for Legend formatting `legend.useHTML` while having `chart.scrollablePlotArea` configured. It will happen, that the Legend completely disappear, as soon as the chart turns swipable.

This happens, because the html legend is put into an svg (`highcharts-root`) wrapper within the `highcharts-fixed` div. As soon as you pull it out, the legend start to work again.

imho a bug within the highcharts lib, too.

What are your solutions to this problems or did it never happend to you?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting us the problem (here and on our GitHub repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8824)

You've definitely right, it's Highcharts bug. You can find the workaround in the report mentioned above, so please refer to it.

To workaround it, you can move all checkboxes to the main container (which should have set `position: relative`), then make the `chart.chartBackground: 'transparent'` and set the old value of the chart's background color to the main container's color. Moving checkboxes can be executed through `chart.events.load` function, but changing background definition should be triggered additionally on `chart.events.redraw` event, that's why I created the global function to toggling the color. All steps you can achieve by this way:

Toggle color function:

```
var toggleBgColor = function(chart) {
  var chartBg = chart.chartBackground
  var container = chart.renderTo
  var chartBgColor = chartBg.attr('fill')

  // Set the chart background to transparent and set old color on container
  chartBg.attr({ fill: 'transparent' })
  container.style.backgroundColor = chartBgColor
}
```

Chart configuration:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load() {
        var checkboxes = this.renderTo.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
        // Move checkboxes to chart container
        checkboxes.forEach(element => {
            this.renderTo.appendChild(element)
        })
        // Toggle chart's background color
        toggleBgColor(this)
      },
    redraw() {
      toggleBgColor(this)
    }
  }
}
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/L3nm0ouq/

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed meanwhile by highcharts, see
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8824